# e.stopPropagation() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have inner and outer element, each of these elements have `onclick()` function and when I click on inner element both `onclick()` functions fire up. I found some examples on SO about this, but I can't get it working. This is what I tried:

```
<div onclick='outerFunction("+someVar+", this);'>
 <label onclick='innerFunction("+someVar+", this);'>
 </label>
</div>
```

javascript

```
function getSnippet(someVar, e){
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
    // rest of code
}

function editSnippet(someVar, e){
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
    // rest of code

}
```

I should mention, that `<div>` and `<label>` are created dinmically using javascript

Comment: In your code, `e` is `this`, i.e. the element itself, not the event object.

Comment: Use jQuery ......... ?

Comment: Yeah, not enough jQuery. More seriously, do NOT **please please** use onclick=""

Comment: `e.stopPropagation();` move it up at top most in the fn.

Comment: If you insist on using `onclick` attribute, then you could do something like `onclick='function(event) { innerFunction(" + someVar + ", this, e); }'`

Comment: I'll give you a tip -> `<div onclick='if (event.target === this) outerFunction("+someVar+", this);'>`, but it seems you really should be using jQuery instead, as you tagged the question with jQuery

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PSS7N/

Comment: @adeneo Thank you, you should post your fiddle as answer so I can accept it

Comment: The other answers with proper event handlers are better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the looks of your question you are passing `this` through as `e` (this being the current object that is being clicked).  Instead of using `onclick` to bind the click event, you should give your element a class like this:

```
<div class="outer">
    <label class="inner">
    </label>
</div>
```

then you can bind the click event using jQuery in your document ready function doing this:

```
$('.inner').on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**EDIT**

Just noticed your comment about passing variables to the  function - this is easy enough using [jQuery and data attributes](http://api.jquery.com/data/) - so for the html you would put the extra variables into data attributes like so:

```
<div class="outer" data-test="variable value here" data-another="another attribute here">
```

and then in your click function you can get these values like this:

```
$('.outer').on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  var testVariable = $(this).data("test");
  var anotherVariable = $(this).data("another")
});
```

Comment: typo - it's e.stopPropagation() - not e.stopPropogation()

Comment: @LorDex I always type that wrong for some reason!  Edited, ta

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the methods when dom is loaded i.e. when dynamically generated elements load completely.

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GsLtN/5/)**

```
$('body').on('click', 'a', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$('<div class="outer"><label class="inner"></label></div>').appendTo('body');
$(this).remove();
});

$('body').on('click', '.outer > *', function(e){
 e.stopPropagation();    
});

$('body').on('click', '.outer', function(){
 alert("outside the box?");    
})
```

Comment: Ok, but maybe you didn't noticed, I pass some variables to inner and outer functions, and I get these variables from database, that's why I used onclick() because I already loaded those variables before.